# Cannot edit a post on security.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Somewhat new to participating on SE. I have been searching around the meta and stack exchange help center but not finding much if any guidance. On [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108722/hi-im-newbie-im-goolgling-every-day-and-night-but-i-cant-find-the-soluti) I am unable to recommend an edit to improve the spelling, grammar, and punctuation by the person posting to improve the quality. **Why is the edit button grayed out and unavailable, but is available on random other posts? Is this a case that a recommended edit is currently pending?**

Below for reference:[image]

Comment: I don't know, telling you that "it works for me" would not be helpful :-). Did you try refreshing the page? Does it work now? It is possible there was a pending edit and it was momentarily blocking you, I guess...

Comment: [Please do not dump Wikipedia content into tag wikis.](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/psa-please-do-not-dump-wikipedia-into-tag-wikis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was already a [pending suggested edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66115) at the time you wanted to submit one. There can only be a single pending suggested edit at a time on a given post. (It's easy to find now because it's been accepted and it appears in the post history, but while the edit was pending, you could know that it existed but there was no easy way for you to find its content.)

If you hover over the grayed out “edit” button, a popup appears to tell you that.